# IntelliJ idea can't start after installed .glsl plugins

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, ide, launch

I was going to use IntelliJ IDEA to edit some .glsl files, so I drag the folder that has those files into it to the link on my desktop. The target of the link is `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2\bin\idea64.exe`.

IntelliJ was launched successfully, but it recommended me to install some plugins about GLSL and restart. After that, it can't be launch anymore. It was stucked in the initial window.[image]

I then typed `idea.bat` in `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2\bin`, here's the error output:

```
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2\bin>idea.bat
2023-11-20 23:13:34,173 [   2288]   WARN - l.NotificationGroupManagerImpl - Notification group CodeWithMe is already registered (group=com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup@1e76695a). Plugin descriptor: PluginDescriptor(name=Code With Me, id=com.jetbrains.codeWithMe, descriptorPath=plugin.xml, path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2\plugins\cwm-plugin, version=212.5284.40, package=null)
2023-11-20 23:13:34,385 [   2500]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:314)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:319)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1739)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1728)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at glsl.language.property.GlslFileType.<init>(GlslFileType.java:14)
        at glsl.language.property.GlslFileType.<clinit>(GlslFileType.java:11)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Unsafe.java:1042)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.java:43)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:186)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Field.java:1105)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:1086)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:418)
        at com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.impl.FileTypeManagerImpl.instantiateFileTypeBean(FileTypeManagerImpl.java:475)
        at com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.impl.FileTypeManagerImpl.mergeOrInstantiateFileTypeBean(FileTypeManagerImpl.java:444)
        at com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.impl.FileTypeManagerImpl.instantiatePendingFileTypes(FileTypeManagerImpl.java:436)
        at com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.impl.FileTypeManagerImpl.doInitializeComponent(FileTypeManagerImpl.java:572)
        at com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.impl.FileTypeManagerImpl.initializeComponent(FileTypeManagerImpl.java:564)
        at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreImpl.initComponent(ComponentStoreImpl.kt:134)
        at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreWithExtraComponents.initComponent(ComponentStoreWithExtraComponents.kt:48)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.initializeComponent$intellij_platform_serviceContainer(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:525)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ServiceComponentAdapter.createAndInitialize(ServiceComponentAdapter.kt:52)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ServiceComponentAdapter.doCreateInstance(ServiceComponentAdapter.kt:36)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstanceUncached(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:113)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstance(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:67)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstance$default(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:60)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.instantiateService(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:1084)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl$preloadServices$1.invoke(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:1056)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl$preloadServices$1.run(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:58)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1407)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doJoin(ForkJoinTask.java:396)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invokeAll(ForkJoinTask.java:853)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl$preloadServices$3.run(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:1076)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1736)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: com.intellij.diagnostic.ImplementationConflictException: Language with ID 'Glsl' is already registered: class glsl.plugin.language.GlslLanguage
        at com.intellij.lang.Language.<init>(Language.java:84)
        at com.intellij.lang.Language.<init>(Language.java:60)
        at com.intellij.lang.Language.<init>(Language.java:56)
        at glsl.language.property.GlslLanguage.<init>(GlslLanguage.java:9)
        at glsl.language.property.GlslLanguage.<clinit>(GlslLanguage.java:6)
        ... 37 more
2023-11-20 23:13:34,391 [   2506]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.2  Build #IC-212.5284.40
2023-11-20 23:13:34,392 [   2507]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 11.0.12; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
2023-11-20 23:13:34,392 [   2507]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Windows 10
2023-11-20 23:13:34,394 [   2509]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin to blame: Better-Glsl-Jetbrain version: 0.0.1
2023-11-20 23:13:34,394 [   2509]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action:
2023-11-20 23:13:37,844 [   5959]  ERROR - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Conflicting component name 'FileTypeManager': class com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.impl.FileTypeManagerImpl and class com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.impl.FileTypeManagerImpl (componentManager=Application (containerState=COMPONENT_CREATED) )
java.lang.Throwable: Conflicting component name 'FileTypeManager': class com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.impl.FileTypeManagerImpl and class com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.impl.FileTypeManagerImpl (componentManager=Application (containerState=COMPONENT_CREATED) )
        at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:182)
        at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreImpl.doAddComponent(ComponentStoreImpl.kt:358)
        at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreImpl.initComponent(ComponentStoreImpl.kt:116)
        at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreWithExtraComponents.initComponent(ComponentStoreWithExtraComponents.kt:48)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.initializeComponent$intellij_platform_serviceContainer(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:525)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ServiceComponentAdapter.createAndInitialize(ServiceComponentAdapter.kt:52)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ServiceComponentAdapter.doCreateInstance(ServiceComponentAdapter.kt:36)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstanceUncached(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:113)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstance(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:67)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstance$default(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:60)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.doGetService(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:590)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.getService(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:573)
        at com.intellij.openapi.client.ClientAwareComponentManager.getFromSelfOrCurrentSession(ClientAwareComponentManager.kt:37)
        at com.intellij.openapi.client.ClientAwareComponentManager.getService(ClientAwareComponentManager.kt:22)
        at com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.FileTypeManager.getInstance(FileTypeManager.java:40)
        at com.intellij.openapi.projectRoots.impl.ProjectJdkTableImpl$1.<init>(ProjectJdkTableImpl.java:52)
        at com.intellij.openapi.projectRoots.impl.ProjectJdkTableImpl.<init>(ProjectJdkTableImpl.java:51)
        at com.intellij.openapi.projectRoots.impl.JavaAwareProjectJdkTableImpl.<init>(JavaAwareProjectJdkTableImpl.java:20)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ConstructorInjectionKt.instantiateUsingPicoContainer(constructorInjection.kt:47)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.instantiateClassWithConstructorInjection(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:877)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ServiceComponentAdapter.createAndInitialize(ServiceComponentAdapter.kt:48)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ServiceComponentAdapter.doCreateInstance(ServiceComponentAdapter.kt:36)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstanceUncached(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:113)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstance(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:67)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstance$default(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:60)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.doGetService(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:590)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.getService(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:573)
        at com.intellij.openapi.client.ClientAwareComponentManager.getFromSelfOrCurrentSession(ClientAwareComponentManager.kt:37)
        at com.intellij.openapi.client.ClientAwareComponentManager.getService(ClientAwareComponentManager.kt:22)
        at com.intellij.openapi.projectRoots.ProjectJdkTable.getInstance(ProjectJdkTable.java:20)
        at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.AndroidSdks.lambda$getAllAndroidSdks$0(AndroidSdks.java:188)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:854)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.ReadAction.compute(ReadAction.java:61)
        at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.AndroidSdks.getAllAndroidSdks(AndroidSdks.java:188)
        at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.AndroidSdks.getAndroidSdkPathsFromExistingPlatforms(AndroidSdks.java:167)
        at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.AndroidSdks.tryToChooseAndroidSdk(AndroidSdks.java:154)
        at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.AndroidSdks.tryToChooseSdkHandler(AndroidSdks.java:130)
        at com.android.tools.idea.updater.SdkComponentSource.getRepoManager(SdkComponentSource.java:98)
        at com.android.tools.idea.updater.SdkComponentSource.initIfNecessary(SdkComponentSource.java:69)
        at com.android.tools.idea.updater.SdkComponentSource.getComponents(SdkComponentSource.java:145)
        at com.android.tools.idea.updater.SdkComponentSource.getAvailableVersions(SdkComponentSource.java:126)
        at com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.UpdateChecker.getExternalPluginUpdates(UpdateChecker.kt:473)
        at com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.UpdateChecker.doUpdateAndShowResult(UpdateChecker.kt:185)
        at com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.UpdateChecker.doUpdateAndShowResult$default(UpdateChecker.kt:158)
        at com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.UpdateChecker$updateAndShowResult$1$1.run(UpdateChecker.kt:114)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2023-11-20 23:13:37,846 [   5961]  ERROR - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.2  Build #IC-212.5284.40
2023-11-20 23:13:37,847 [   5962]  ERROR - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - JDK: 11.0.12; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
2023-11-20 23:13:37,854 [   5969]  ERROR - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - OS: Windows 10
2023-11-20 23:13:37,863 [   5978]  ERROR - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Last Action:
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Delete the Plugins directory: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#plugins-directory. See also https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007568559.